# How can I install ipython5 in the anaconda navigator?

Tags: ipython, anaconda

How can I install ipython5 in the anaconda navigator? It currently is running 4.2.0, but the latest ipython release is not available as an option.

Comment: try `conda update --all` or `conda update ipython`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of ipython has now been added to the anaconda package list.

Choose: Anaconda navigator > Environment > Update index

Then search for the ipython package: right click it and select version 5.0.0